# Empty exception when saving a Connector configuration in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm creating a simple Microsoft Teams Connector that's intended to broadcast messages from an external application to a channel within teams, with some follow-on functionality to come later.

For now, essentially it's a branded version of the "Incoming Webhook" Connector. To use it, my expectation is that the user will copy a webhook URL from MS Teams and paste it into the external app, the way apps like Pivotal Tracker and others work.

I've registered the Connector on the "Connectors Developer Dashboard" and am testing it out by manually sideloading a manifest file into teams.

The external app is serving a configuration HTML page that's specified in the manifest per the docs. The page has the MS Teams Javascript SDK loaded and displays the `webhookUrl` in a copy paste input element populated by a `microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings()` call.

This all seems to work fine, but I can't the the configuration to save. Here's the error I see in the browser console:

```
Received error from connectors:
{  
   "seq":1538668381965,
   "timestamp":1538680770343,
   "flightSettings":{  
      "Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
      "AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
      "SPAEnabled":true,
      "ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,
      "ClientRoutingEnabled":true,
      "EnableYammerGroupOption":true,
      "EnableFadeMessage":false,
      "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,
      "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,
      "DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,
      "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false
   },
   "status":500,
   "clientType":"SkypeSpaces",
   "connectorType":"760108a2-3c13-45e2-aa70-11a8acd32e3a",
   "name":"handleMessageError",
   "nonPIIInfo":"{\"exception\":{}}"
}
```

As you can see, the exception is blank. I've tried the suggestions from similar questions (removing `validDomains` in the manifest and pre-pending the ones in the Connector Dashboard with protocols) to no avail.

How can I find out why my configuration is not getting saved?

*Note: normally I'd just file a ticket with the MS Teams dev support team for something like this, but this seems to be the only support channel available. For MS Teams staff, the connector ID I have is `760108a2-3c13-45e2-aa70-11a8acd32e3a`.*

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest? I'll try uploading at my end.

Comment: Here's a copy of the [manifest](https://gist.github.com/henrypoydar/bc6e5f1b9a4ec18e2e08e59da4b2c5ce), and here's the [zip](https://staging.statushero.com/microsoft-teams/status-hero-ms-team-v1_0_7.zip). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings() code is commented out in your config page. It's required step for Connector configuration to work. Please have a look at [Connector Configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-creating#integrating-the-configuration-experience).Here is [Connector config page sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml).

Here is how you can call setSettings:

```
  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
       entityId: "statushero",
       contentUrl: "https://staging.statushero.com/microsoft-teams/configuration.html",
        configName: "statusheroConfig"
     });
```

Make sure that you add **https://staging.statushero.com** in valid domains section in Connector dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, @wajeed. I did indeed attempt to follow the docs before posting, but was left with the impression that `setSettings` was only needed "if the user tries to update an existing configuration for your connector". In any case that change worked - thanks again. For valid domains, I'm assuming we need to put the protocol and leave them out of the manifest, correct? Will wildcard subdomains work? Finally, is this the only dev support channel for Teams integrations? (A team for Teams devs would be helpful!)

Comment: The documentation has been clarified and will be updated in the next few days.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Is there any way to better troubleshoot problem of such a kind? I have the same issue, but `validDomains` are filled in correctly and doesn't seem to be causing the issue. The connector I'm talking about was initially working after I've created it.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT the documentation page isn't working. It says "Oops! Page Not Found".

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT we've had Status Hero submitted for publication for months now. What else do we need to do to get it published? Explaining the sideloading process to our customers has been burdensome. Thanks! (Connector ID: 760108a2-3c13-45e2-aa70-11a8acd32e3a)